# Proving a theorem about isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F$ of dimensions $n$ and $m$, respectively, and let $\beta, \gamma$ be ordered bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. Then the function $\Phi:L(V,W) \to M_{m \times n}(F)$,defined by $\Phi(T)=[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$ for $T \in L(V,W)$, is an isomorphism.

To prove this theorem, we need to show that it is linear, it is injective and surjective.

I want to ask specifically about proving subjectivity.

We can let $T \in L(V,W)$, then $\phi(T)=[T]^\gamma_\beta$. And we let $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$. I know $\phi(T)=[T]^\gamma_\beta$ is a matrix of m rows and n columns, to prove surjectivity, we need to prove that $[T]^\gamma_\beta= A$. My question is how to proceed after this step?

Comment: Friedberg insel spence? haha I remember having trouble with this theorem when I first studied it 2 years back

Comment: yeah Friedberg.

Comment: From what I remember, they do provide a proof. Is there a particular step there which is unclear?

Comment: They provided a sketch, I want to ask about surjectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove surjectivity, you need to show that for each $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$, there exists some $T \in L(V,W)$ such that $[T]_{\beta}^\gamma = A$. To prove this, it suffices to construct the map $T$ directly.

If $\beta = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ and $\gamma = (w_1, \ldots, w_m)$ then consider the map defined by $$T(v_j) = a_{1j}w_1 + a_{2j}w_2 + \cdots + a_{mj}w_m$$
for each $j$. Check that this is indeed a map in $L(V,W)$ and check that $[T]_{\beta}^\gamma = A$.

Comment: Can you specify checking $$T(v_j) = a_{1j}w_1 + a_{2j}w_2 + \cdots + a_{mj}w_m$$ is a map in $L(V,W)$? Will that be straight forward by saying that  since map in $L(V,W)$ is has the form $$T(v_j) = a_{1j}w_1 + a_{2j}w_2 + \cdots + a_{mj}w_m$$ and it is closed in multiplication and addition in vector space, it is indeed a map?